# How do I search an iframe for a specific image or grab the source code

Tags: iframe

My main goal is to search an iframe for a specific image. I know what the image will be (abc_clicked.gif) but am not sure how I can access the iframe to either:

1) search the iframe for the image itself
2) grab the source code in which I will manually search myself for the image

I am looking trying to accomplish this with javascript, as I don't see how PHP could help me at all in this case.

Anyone have any ideas???? I'm lost....

Comment: This is only possible if the IFRAME is in the same domain. (Or if you build a relay in PHP)

Answer (score 1):

If the iFrame is hosted on the same domain, you can access the DOM the same as you would for the main page using `contentDocument`.

For example:

```
var iframeElement = document.getElementById('myiframe');
var imageElement = iframeElement.contentDocument.getElementById('myImage');
```

Comment: `IFRAME` was not made by Apple.  **Please** don't write iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

(assuming you're working in a Web page and looking for a JavaScript solution)

If the iframed page is in a different domain, there's not much you can do.

If it's in the same domain, here is a cross-browser way to access it's content:

```
var doc=ifr.contentWindow||ifr.contentDocument;
if (doc.document) doc=doc.document;
```

You can then search your iframe:

```
var imgs = doc.getElementsByTagName("img");
// etc.
```

Your second option is also valid (but might be more complicated), use ajax to retrieve and parse the page source.